# How to fix chrome certificate issues after removing Fiddler root cert?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, certificate

I am getting `NET::ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY` certificate error for a website. I have uninstalled all the Fiddler certificates from the local and user certificate stores. Also, I do not see my domain listed in the Chrome's HSTS list. I have restarted my computer. The certificate is not expired also. I still see the below certificate issue in my chrome. The same website does not show certificate errors in other browsers. I am using windows 10 enterprise and chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 66 or later distrusts all Symantec SSL/TLS certificates issued before June 1, 2016. Google planned to release the public version on April 17, 2018.
A website that has a Symantec SSL/TLS certificate issued before June 1, 2016 will display the error as shown in the question when accessed via Chrome 66 or later:

> NET::ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY

More details about it can be found [here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/ALERT2566.html)